# The size of $\{g\in G: |g|\leq k\}$ which $G$ is finitely generated group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group, assume that $S$ is finite generating set of $G$. It is known that any finitely generated group is a countable group. We define  by $|g|$ the word norm of
an element $g$ with respect to $S$, i.e. $ ||g||_S=\inf\{k\geq 1: g= s_k s_{k-1}\ldots s_1,   s_i\in S, 
1\leq i\leq k\} $.

Fix $k\in \mathbb{N}$. What can say about size of the set $\{g\in G: |g|=k\}$. Can I say the set of $\{g\in G: |g|\leq k\}$ is finite set in $G$?

Is it true that it depend on structure of $G$?

Comment: Either you need to assume that $S$ is closed under inverses or you need to take $s_i \in S^{\pm 1}$ in your definition of $||g||_S$. This topic is called the growth of the group (w.r.t. $S$). There are some significant results, such as Gromov's theorem that a group has polynomial growth iff it is virtually nilpotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly say that the set $\{g\in G:|g|= k\}$ is finite; there are finitely many words of length $k\in \mathbb{N}$ using elements in $S$, and so there can only be finitely many elements in $G$ that they collectively represent.

Then the set $\{g\in G:|g|\leq k\}$ is the union of finitely many finite sets (them being the $\{g\in G:|g|= i\}$  for each $i\leq k$), making it itself finite.